# easybill REST Api Increase Limit Data

Tags: php, json, rest

Unfortunately I have another question about the REST API from easybill :-(

Link: https://www.easybill.de/api/
or: https://api.easybill.de/rest/v1/swagger.json

I hope you can read my english. I use the Google Translator.

I have the problem that I can only query a maximum of 100 customer data.

On the Api internet page it says, "All result lists are limited to 100 by default. This limit can be increased by the query parameter limit to a maximum of 1000."

But I can't find any help on the internet on how to increase this limit in my code.

I hope you can help me.

Here my Code:

```
$url = "https://api.easybill.de/rest/v1/customers";
$ch = curl_init();
$accesstoken = "XXXXXXX";
$headr = array();
$headr[] = 'Content-length: 0';

$headr[] = 'Content-type: application/json';
$headr[] = 'Authorization: Bearer '.$accesstoken;

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,$headr);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPGET, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$result=curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

$data = json_decode($result,true);
$users=$data;

print '<pre>';
print_r($users);
print '</pre>';
```

Best greetings from Germany

Comment: Hello referring to https://www.easybill.de/api/ it states that "All result lists are limited to 100 by default. This limit can be increased by the query parameter limit to a maximum of 1000." so just append , ?limit=1000 to your $url

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Query string means that the parameter belongs to the url and for GET it is the only option to pass any parameters.

So you append it with '?' separated to the url.

`https://api.easybill.de/rest/v1/customers` gets `https://api.easybill.de/rest/v1/customers?limit=1000`

But this is not the best way so solve your problem. If there are 1001 customers you will never receive this last one.

According to the documentation there is also a `page` parameter. So it is better to send multiple requests and increment the page number.

So call these urls until you wont get any data back:

```
https://api.easybill.de/rest/v1/customers?page=1
https://api.easybill.de/rest/v1/customers?page=2
https://api.easybill.de/rest/v1/customers?page=3
...
```

Comment: The URL https://api.easybill.de/rest/v1/customers?=limit=1000 looks incorrect , note the extra "=" before the limit parameter.

Comment: @mkane thanks for pointing it out, it was a copy&pase error